# Symfony 4 and Sonata News Bundle Error during Intallation

Tags: php, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-4.3

I got the following error during installing SonataNewsBundle.

```
Unable to register extension "Sonata\FormatterBundle\Extension\ControlFlowExtension" as it is already registered in . (which is being imported from "/home/yoesoff/Documents/projects/oblog/config/routes/sonata_admin.yaml"). Make sure there is a loader supporting the "sonata_admin" type.
```

[image: Error]

And following Error

```
The target-entity App\Entity\SonataMediaMedia cannot be found in 'App\Entity\SonataClassificationCollection#media'.
```

[image]

I just followed the official documentation from [here](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/news/3-x/doc/reference/installation.html).

Anybody can help regarding it?

Comment: As far as I understand Flex *should* create `App\Entity\SonataMediaMedia` instead of us having to use easy extends to generate entities in the `App\Application` namespace but this seems not to be happening. Not sure what to do about it though...

Comment: Yusuf did you find a solution for the first error? 'Unable to register extension "Sonata\FormatterBundle\Extension\ControlFlowExtension" as it is already registered in . (which is being imported from "/home/yoesoff/Documents/projects/oblog/config/routes/sonata_admin.yaml"). Make sure there is a loader supporting the "sonata_admin" type.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a step missing in the documentation - looks like we manually need to add an extra package that creates the missing classes:

`composer require sonata-project/media-orm-pack`

Note that if you are using `sonata-project/classification-bundle`, you need to fix annotations for `App\Entity\SonataMediaMedia::$category` like so:

```
/**
 * ORM\ManyToOne(
 *     targetEntity="App\Entity\SonataClassificationCategory",
 *     cascade={"persist"}
 * )
 * ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 *
 * @var SonataClassificationCategory
 */
protected $category;
```

If it helps, as far as I understand we should be skipping the `sonata:easy-extends:generate` steps when using Symfony 4 / Flex.

The Flex recipes should be creating classes in our `App\Entity` namespace.

If they do not it will be something along the lines of the above where things need added manually.